# How to choose the smoothing method and factors that best capture the trend in data?

Tags: machine-learning, time-series, python, forecasting, smoothing

I have a time-series data that I will be using to forecast the future using machine learning algorithms such as LSTM. Prior to the forecast, I need to smooth the data to remove the noise and capture the trend which is what I aim to forecast (long term trend rather than a single value).

I am confused how to systematically choose the best method for smoothing the data to capture the trend. I have done some research and tried it myself, and it seems to me that double exponential smoothing is my best option. If so, then how do I choose alpha and beta in a justifiable way? I am using python.